# GoLang Parse Point DataType

Tags: postgresql, go

In my DB i have a table that require a coordinate value.
such value is stored as a

> Point DataType

however when i try to obtain such value, GO responds with an error:

> unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *models.Point

this is my Model

```
type Business struct {
    ID int `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Owner string `json:"owner,omitempty"`
    Coordinates Point `json:"coordinates,omitempty"`
    Reason string `json:"reason,omitempty"`
    BusinessBranches []BusinessBranches `json:"reason,omitempty"`
}
```

and this is the Point type model

```
type Point struct {
    X float64 `json:"lat"`
    Y float64 `json:"lon"`
}
```

in my controller i call the selection of Business.

```
func (b *BusinessRepoImpl) Select() ([]models.Business, error) {
    business_list := make([]models.Business, 0)
    rows, err := b.Db.Query("SELECT id, name, owner, coordinates, reason FROM business")
    if err != nil {
        return business_list, err
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        business := models.Business{}
        err := rows.Scan(&business.ID, &business.Name, &business.Owner, &business.Coordinates, &business.Reason)
        if err !=  nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            break
        }
        business_list = append(business_list, business)
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return business_list, err
    }
    return business_list, nil
}
```

anyone know how to parse such DataType, so i can read it and store it?
Thanks. :)

Comment: The easiest way is probably to implement sql.Scanner interface with your Point type, and parse the data coming from the database. You have to figure out how the data is returned, it looks like it is getting a []uint8.

Comment: The []uint8 return this: KDEyLjEyNjgxNDIsLTg2LjI3NTQwMDAwMDAwMDAwNSk= i need to convert that data into his numeric value.

Comment: That looks like base64 encoded data. Decode it, see what it shows. Btw, isn't Point a postgres data type? Maybe there is a Point struct somewhere in postgres sql drivers?

Comment: Actually yes, i put at the beginning that i have a table whose column type was a Point DataType, however postgres don't have a Point struct, so i need to parse it

Comment: I base64 decoded that text, and it prints: (12.1268142,-86.275400000000005) I guess you can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you need to set to set a structure with the current lat, long and then unmarshal from the database.